# Newtonsoft DeserializeObject error after going from .Net Framework 4.6.1 Console App to Core 2.0 console App

Tags: c#, json, json.net, visual-studio-2017

Using .Net Framework 4.6.1 this works perfectly:

```
private DataTable GetRESTData(string pUri)
{
    var json = ReadFromUri(pUri);
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

    string StrContent = ((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)obj).Last.ToString();
    StrContent = StrContent.Substring(9, StrContent.Length - 9);

    DataTable dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(StrContent);
    return dt;
}
```

This also works:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(StrContent.Substring(9, StrContent.Length - 9), (typeof(DataTable)));
```

But I can't find anything that works on CORE 2.0 Console App, I always get:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Data.DataTable' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either chang...

If I watch the string `StrContent.Substring(9, StrContent.Length - 9)` as JSON or as a string, it's perfectly formatted.

I installed NewtonSoft from Nuget Package Manager.

EDIT: I'm using Visual Studio 2017. If I run this on project with Framework 4.6.1 it works perfectly, Project with CORE 2.0 shows the error I posted above.

Comment: can you post what the JSON looks like in both cases?

Comment: uploaded JSON string here:
https://uploadfiles.io/25ar3
it's the same in both cases. This is the string i send to DeserializeObject.

Comment: @JCIsola If the question is resolved, don't indicate that in the question title. Instead, mark the answer that helped you the most as accepted via the check mark below the vote counter.

Answer (score 3):

The current stable vesion of [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json) library does not support serializing DataSets/DataTables as in the full .NET version.

This is because the library (version 10.0.3) targets the NETStandard 1.3, but the [DataSet/DataTable support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devfish/2017/05/15/exploring-datatable-and-sqldbadapter-in-asp-net-core-2-0/) was added on Net Core 2.0.

The current beta version targets NetStandard 2.0 and **does** support serializing datasets, so if you update your reference to use the latest beta package [Newtonsoft.Json/11.0.1-beta1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/11.0.1-beta1) or wait until a stable version is released, you will be able to serialize/deserialize.

You can check by yourself, if you serialize the following `DataTable` as JSON on .NET core (Newtonsoft.Json/10.0.3):

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(string));
dt.Rows.Add("value");
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
```

You will get something like this:

```
{
  "DataTable.RemotingVersion": {
    "Major": 2,
    "Minor": 0,
    "Build": -1,
    "Revision": -1,
    "MajorRevision": -1,
    "MinorRevision": -1
  },
  "XmlSchema": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>\r\n<xs:schema xmlns=\"\" ... </diffgr:diffgram>"
}
```

But if you target the current beta version (11.0.1-beta1) you get:

```
[
  {
    "Column1": "value"
  }
]
```

There is an issue on the library about this [1409](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1409)